# Working with SQLite database and Camera API in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-camera

I need to develop an android app that achieves the following:

1. Create an activity which takes a picture on a button click.
2. Once the picture is taken, have two buttons save and compare.
3. The picture should be saved in a database if save button is clicked.
4. If compare button is clicked, the picture should be compared with all other pictures in the database.
5. If the picture matches with the one in the database, the name of the picture stored in the database should be displayed.

I know how to use the Camera API to take a picture. But I don't have an idea of how to save the same picture in a database and compare it with all other pictures in the database.

If my idea is wrong please correct me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need is within these tutorials so check this link:
http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6

The logic for comparing the pictures you will have to write yourself though because I can't predict what type of comparison you want. Except that how to connect to db to store data plus getting bitmap from the camera everything is in those tutorials.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the picture in your database. Instead save it on the SDcard/internal storage and save the url in your database. (Simpler approach)

As far as comparing with other pictures, you will need to implement some image recognition/pattern matching algos.